# Why does my Large() formula give me an error using dynamic arrays?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a pivot table and I use `=INDEX($A$5:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A))` to know the numbers of rows in the pivot table. I then use this number to calculate the top 5 using
`=LARGE(Array,{1;2;3;4;5})` which works fine, but when I use
`=LARGE((array1-array2),{1;2;3;4;5})` it give me #N/A as a result; array1 and array2 are base on the formula above `(=INDEX($A$5:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A)))`

I try using it by parts to see if there is something wrong, but when I use
`=$B$5:INDEX($B:$B,COUNTA($B:$B))-$E$5:INDEX($E:$E,COUNTA($E:$E))` itself it gives me what I need but when I use that in the array part [Large(array,k)] to see the top 5 it give me #N/A...

Any help or ways to go around that problem would be appreciated.

Edit:

| Product | 2001 | 2000 | Varriacion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pencil | 100 | 150 | -33% |
| Pen | 150 | 130 | +15% |
| Table | 40 | 50 | -20% |

I use `=INDEX($A$2:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A))` to know the number of rows in the pivot table in this case 3 and outside the Pivot Table I calculated the top 3 variation using `=LARGE($D$2:INDEX($D:$D,COUNTA($D:$D)),{1;2;3})` and then use `=INDEX($A$2:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A)),MATCH(Result[1],=INDEX($D$2:INDEX($D:$D,COUNTA($D:$D)),0))` to match the number with the respective product automatically.

Result[1]: This is the result cell from the Large() formula in the side

This works fine, when I change from product to location (example) it will update and I will see the top three in the calculations in the side. But When I do it to know the absolute variance (column 2001 - column 2000) I do :

`=LARGE($B$2:INDEX($B:$B,COUNTA($B:$B))-$C$2:INDEX($C:$C,COUNTA($C:$C)),{1;2;3})` and in here i get the #N/A so I cant get the Top 3.

When I manually do `=$B$2:INDEX($B:$B,COUNTA($B:$B))-$C$2:INDEX($C:$C,COUNTA($C:$C))` to see if is posible to get the result this way I get the difference in the respective cells but when I use that as an Array in the Large() formula i won't work.

*The variance column is not part of the Pivot table, is just something I add next to it so I can also see the variation and is already automated by using the GetPivot() formula. The pivot table information in this example is just Product, 2001 and 2000.

Comment: Can you elaborate how you get array1 and array2? I am not understanding what you mean when you say they are based on the ```INDEX``` function you are using. Perhaps some sample data and expected output would be helpful to include

Comment: I have set up a sample based on your description, and it works for me.  I suspect your issue is with your `INDEX` formula - what you posted (`=INDEX($A$5:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A))`) is not a valid formula.  Please update your post with your _exact_ formulas, and some sample data

Answer (score 0):

Replicating your setup, I get the result you want, without `#N/A` errors.

[image]

From comments, you have blanks in you Pivot data.  These will cause the `COUNTA` to return invalid results.

The solution is to `COUNTA` a column with no blanks.  Column `A` serves that purpose

```
=LARGE($B$2:INDEX($B:$B,COUNTA($A:$A))-$C$2:INDEX($C:$C,COUNTA($A:$A)),{1;2;3})
```

[image]

Demonstration of the problem

[image]

Comment: I just try my own example in Excel and you are right it works... But i don't understand why the one with real data doesn't...  There is nothing below the pivot table and there are only conditional formats that I add but that shouldn't affect it... There isn't any clash between cell otherwise would give me an split error...It doesn't even work when I just one the Largest not even top 5, still give me ```#N/A``` ...

Comment: Have you tried using "Evaluate Formula" (on the Formulas tab)?  Examine the result of each step, especially the ranges returned by the INDEX's.  Maybe a screen shot of your sheet would help

Comment: Just want to make sure about something, in the pivot tables when there are empty cells are those consider 0 or "" ?? because i was playing around with the example and ones I add a number it gave me ```#N/A``` but ones I add other number next to it to complete the difference it update to the corresponding result.

Comment: Nope... it doesn't work either I just use the pivot settings to make the empty cells 0 and still got ```#N/A```

Comment: I can't use "Evaluate Formula" since I use Mac not Windows and that is not available in the Excel of Mac's

Comment: When a catagory that is being Pivoted is empty, the Pivot produces an empty cell.  That won't be counted by the `COUNTA`, so that is throwing of your formula.  Change the Count range to Column A.    I'll update the answer shortly

Comment: I just found the problem in my data:  when I use ```$B$2:INDEX($B:$B,COUNTA($B:$B))-$C$2:INDEX($C:$C,COUNTA($C:$C))``` with the real data it gives me a dynamic array of the whole range but at the end it has an ```#N/A``` at the end which is why when use the Large() formula with that array give me the ```#N/A``` ... I just have the whole range but it ends with an ```#N/A``` for no reason... I did find a workaround by using IFERROR() outside the array part Large(IFERROR(ARRAY),k) though i am not convinced how reliable the data would end up been since I don't know where the ```#N/A``` comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I just understood why I got `#N/A` ... the problem with the example was that it was shown as a table and in a pivot table the header is different... in column B1 there is always "Column labels" while in the rest of the columns there is just empty space where you can't modify since is Pivot Table. So since I used `$B$2:INDEX($B:$B,COUNTA($B:$B))-$C$2:INDEX($C:$C,COUNTA($C:$C))` the `COUNTA($B:$B))` will give me 1 more than the others, in this case `COUNTA($C:$C)` .

After fixing the formula to equalize the columns counts for all cases it fixes the problem.

Thanks for the help.